# Cycles per Instruction - Does a line of code in assembly sum different cpi operation?

Tags: performance, assembly, x86

Imagine you have two instructions in assembly:

```
movl $10, %ecx
movl 0(%eax), %edx
```

The CPI for movements is 1, and for acess to memory is 2.

For the 1st line CPI = 1. For the second one, is the CPI= 2 or 3? Do we sum the acess to the memory (2 cycles) + the move cost, or just consider the acess to memory?

Answer (score 5):

Cycle counting doesn't really work anymore, ever since the Pentium 4 hit the market. Deep pipelines, three-level memory cache hierarchies, multiple execution units with out-of-order execution, branch prediction...

It is often possible to make a good guess about the timing of a bigger piece of code but for two isolated instructions it is virtually impossible (unless one instruction happens to be DIV or IDIV, then we know it must be bad). The context is important because dependency chains play a big role (critical path).

In real code, your two instructions might well contribute nothing at all to the total timing, if they execute in the latency shadow of some other instruction. On the other hand, if the value addressed by EAX is not in any of the caches then it costs you hundreds of cycles, or many thousands if the data has to be paged in from disk...

The current [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Optimization Reference Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.html) contains everything that you need. It contains tables with cycle counts (latency and throughput) for most instructions, as well as several hundred pages of explanation why simple cycle counting doesn't work.

Comment: Well that's not really what i asked, since i'm learning the basics. But thanks for participating ;)

Comment: The cycle count for your two instructions is between 0 and 10000, depending on circumstances. Register-to-register MOV has latency and througput 0.5, the memory access cause latency 4 under ideal conditions (L1 cache, address stable, offset < 2048); could be less for a forwarded store but usually it'll be more, or much more. In other words: you can count cycles but the numbers will be completely meaningless.

Comment: You are over reaching behond my question and i don't know why. If a move instruction costs 1 cicle and a access to memory 2, that instruction will cost 2 or 3 cicles? Very simple question...

Comment: No, it won't. It can cost you no cycles at all, or dozens, or thousands. You can write the number **4.5** next to your two instructions but it will be completely meaningless, with no relation at all to the actual runtime behaviour of your code. Besides, the numbers vary wildly between CPUs.

Comment: Jesus crist, is a simple exercice... It's not performance analysis. It's simple math!

Comment: Note: In modern CPUs are more than only one execution pipelines and with a certain order of the instruction placement and if no dependence between the instructions, the instructions can be execute simultaneously. And so it is not a simple math for to calculate the cicles of a single instruction. It depends also how other instructions together are placed around.

Comment: Thanks man... did you guys started learning from the top or from the bottom?

Comment: Bottom. Z80 CPU with 1 KByte RAM and hexadecimal display. Programs had to be entered as hex codes. Teaches you a lot about how assemblers work, if you have to do their job on paper or in your head... I'd recommend [OllyDbg](http://www.ollydbg.de/) and/or [MASM32](http://www.masm32.com/) (complete IDE with one-key running of programs) for hands-on experimentation. Inline assembler in C/C++ is more convenient, though. With the RDTSC instruction you can read the CPU cycle counter, hence you can measure the actual cycles taken by a piece of code. It's also available in C/C++ as `__rdtsc()`.